# Qt 5.4 with Visual Studio 2013 - QtCored.dll missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2013

Each time I reopen my solution in Visual Studio 2013 ultimate and start debugging, I get:

> The program can't start because Qt5Cored.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this program.

<strike>Rebuild</strike> `Build->Project Only->Link Only` solves the problem. I have 3 non-Qt projects in my solution, statically linked with the 4th Qt Application project. I'm using `msvc2013_opengl x86` build. Have any of you experienced this before? Should you need more information, please ask.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: QtcoreD.dll is for DEBUG... Qtcore.dll is release. Don't use debug versions out QT

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to post a answer later

Comment: do you have pre-build or post build events configured in your solution?

Comment: I don't have any stated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use

```
PATH=%QTDIR%\bin;%PATH%;
```

following wont work

```
PATH=$(QTDIR)\bin;$(PATH);
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how rebuilding the project solves the issue. But following steps should fix it correctly.

Make sure `QTDIR` environment variable correctly points to your Qt directory.

Right click on executable project and select `Properties`.

Set `Configuration` to `All Configurations`

In `Configuration Properties` -> `Debugging`, set `Environment` to following

```
PATH=$(QTDIR)\bin;$(PATH);
```

Comment: Type %QTDIR%\bin in the address bar of an explorer window and press enter. Check whether Qt5cored.dll is in the directory that opens.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know what more to check

Comment: @LogicStuff `This isn't helping` is not an helpful message

Comment: It means nothing's changed.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue. The $(QTDIR) isn't present in macro list (button Macros>>) when I click the Edit in the combobox of the Environment but is present in other places (e.g. Macros>> button when editing include directories). Thus, as $(QTDIR) is not recognized, the environment is set to PATH="\bin;$(PATH)" and the DLL is not found. Do you see the $(QTDIR) in the macros list? The question is, why the $(QTDIR) doesn't exist for the Environment setting, I am thinking about submitting a bug to QT developers, that's why I am asking whether it is the same for you.

Comment: @LogicStuff, if you are also having same problem as Martin, then you would be able to get this working by using full path to Qt bin dir instead of using `$(QTDIR)\bin` in your `Environment` setting

Comment: @Marian Spanik Pardon me the delay, on the contrary, I have $(QTDIR) present in enviroment macros, but not in others.

Answer (score 1):

dudekings solution works, but this works for me too (tm) and might be slightly better:

```
PATH=$(QTDIR)\bin;$(Path)
```

because afaik it uses the VS environment variables you can set in property sheets etc. Note that it's **not PATH**, but **Path**...
You might also need the Qt platform plugins (aka qwindows.dll). For that also add the line:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=$(QTDIR)\plugins\platforms
```

Note that the variable QTDIR is set by the VS Qt-Addin, so make sure you have that installed and your project properly set up to be a Qt project (as-in managed by the Addin)! Otherwise it properly won't work.